# Reading office 365 emails with only delegate access

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to read office 365 emails in c# only using the **delegate permission** in aad since I **dont have the right to grant admin consent**?

If so how can this be done because I cannot find any thing regarding this.

I have got the access token but when I try to access the emails but it gives 403 forbidden error.

Comment: do you have any update on it?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the api you are using. Assuming you are now using [list message api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). The required permissions for delegated type is like below.

[image]

In Azure AD, we can see that all of the 3 api permissions don't require admin consent, so it's ok to call this API without admin consent.

[image]

We need to use auth code flow to generate access token. You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045288/14574199) about the test result using auth code flow with an un-consent api permission.

For asp.net core MVC application, you can write code like [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) to integrate Azure AD and Graph SDK to consent API permission and call graph api.

Here for example the API permission we required is `Mail.Read`, then the code in `Program.cs` should like:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
                //.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "Mail.Read" })
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Then when we sign in the app, we would get this dialog to consent on behalf of the user. If we don't set `Mail.Read` in `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi`, we won't get this consent dialog.

[image]

By the way, if we don't give user consent, we would get below error like below when call the api via graph client like `var a = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();`

[image]

If we give user consent, then it should work. Since I don't have a mail resource, so I got this information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To check the mail with delegated access, you can use the below query:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/$value
```

The delegated permissions required:

[image]